# div content its out of the div when padding is added

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Usuario</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the css

```
.form-wrapper{
    padding-top: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I supposed that the `.form-wrapper` content its inside the div but when I added the border ,this was the result
[image]

I don't know how the inputs are outside the div boders

Comment: Unable to recreate the issue. What browser are you in? Are you using any other includes?

Comment: on firefox 58.0.1

Comment: Is that piece of css (`.form-wrapper`) the only content of css/styles.css? If not, share that file's styles too.

Comment: this is the full css content

Comment: I checked 58.0.1 too and it is fine. Could you share the actual link?

Comment: row inside container

Comment: Its on  localhost @curveball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow bootstrap rules by adding `row` inside `container` and the issue will get fixed.

*By the way the issue appear only on full width and it's related to float not being cleared correctly and will appear even without padding-top specified*

```css
.form-wrapper {
  padding-top: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-wrapper row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Usuario</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```